# Grabbing random samples from pandas dataframe but only one per value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset is an athlete dataset, and one column is the `AthleteName`. There are 38 observations but some athletes participated more than once, so there are in total 31 athletes. 
I would like to extract a "random" sample with 31 observations, where there would be all the observations that appear only one time, and for the ones that appear more time, one picked at random.

I tried doing something like this but it gives me an error:

```
sample_fem = pd.DataFrame
total = 0
while total <= 31:
    sample = female_dec.sample(n=1, replace=False)
    sample = sample.reset_index()
    if sample["AthleteName"][0] not in sample_fem["AthleteName"]:
       sample_fem.append(sample)
       total +=1 


  File "<ipython-input-561-249bb5b47652>", line 6, in <module>
    if sample["AthleteName"][0] not in sample_fem["AthleteName"]:

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `sample_fem = pd.DataFrame` will set `sample_fem` to be the type `DataFrame`, which is likely causing your error. You can't do `sample_fem["AthleteName"]` on a type.

Comment: @NickBecker you're right. Changed it for sample_fem["DecathleteName"].values but it's taking ages to run, so I'm tinking it's not right.. any ideas?

Comment: It's possible there is a better way to do what you're trying to do, but it's not completely clear what you're trying to do. If I'm understanding correctly, one faster way might be to use `df.duplicated` to create a flag variable as to whether a record is a duplicate and then randomly drop duplicates of the "True"s. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want in your "random sample" is:

- all of the records for athletes that only occur once in the data
- a single record for each athlete that occurs two or more times in the data, chosen at random

To do this, first we build a dataframe and indicate whether a record occurs more than once.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,2]})
df['dup_flag'] = df.duplicated(keep=False)
df
    a   dup_flag
0   0   False
1   1   False
2   2   True
3   3   False
4   4   True
5   4   True
6   5   False
7   6   False
8   2   True
```

Next, we separate into the "uniques" and the "dups", based on the flag variable we created.

```py
uniques = df.loc[df.dup_flag == False]
dups = df.loc[df.dup_flag == True]
```

With that just need to define a random order for our index before using `drop_duplicates` on our `dups` dataframe. Then, we can just combine the results.

```py
random_order_idx = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(dups)))
random_dups_deduped = dups.iloc[random_order_idx].drop_duplicates()

pd.concat([uniques, random_dups_deduped])
    a   dup_flag
0   0   False
1   1   False
3   3   False
6   5   False
7   6   False
5   4   True
2   2   True
```